# A shortcut to switch audio output and play podcast for 15min

Tags: iphone, automation, podcasts, shortcuts-app, homepod

I use to listen to podcast before sleep. But that actually means:

1. On iPhone 12, open overcast app and start playing
2. Switch audio output to homepod
3. Set it to stop playing after 15min (I expect to be sleeping at this time)

Is it possible to automate that?

Today I spend some noticed the shortcuts app and managed to create a shortcut to start a 40min timer when I say "Hey Siri, Laundry timer". But automate my sleep routine seems much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The key item you're missing is the overcast sleep timer. Overcast now supports this with 'Sleep After Time'
I've [created a shortcut you can add](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/29c2a345fe59482f96507cd678a0a682) that should accomplish what you're looking for. (Although you'll need to set the playback destination, since I don't have a homepod)

[image: Overcast Bedtime Routine Shortcut]